# Spring Cloud Kafka custom consumer factory

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, kafka-consumer-api

I have third party library that wrapped Kafka consumer with some security and discovery features. It has some additional properties in Kafka configuration. This library has custom consumer factory

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = CustomKafkaClient.createConsumer(configs)
```

It works in plain Java, but my point is to put this custom consumer to the Spring Cloud Kafka.
Is there any beans that I can customize for consumer creating? I was only able to find the ConsumerConfigCustomizer interface, but it doesn't cover consumer creating.